# connection string based on ms access version present in PC

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have developed a windows application.
My development environment is win7, office2007, C#, VS2010, Winforms.
My application stores data in MS Access.

Is there any way with which i can create a connection string based on MS Access version present in PC?

Comment: Are the clients accessing the database via Microsoft Access or your application?  What driver / access database version is going to determine what connection string to use - not what version of access is installed on the machine.

Comment: Ms Access itself is a database for my application. I also need to identify which Oledb driver is installed in the PC along with MS Access version

Comment: Keep in mind that an access database (filename.mdb or filename.accdb) does not require Microsoft Access to be installed on the machine to be used by a .net application.  It is only relevant if are opening and using the database inside Microsoft Access which it does not sound like you are.

Comment: Great thanks. But then another question arises that how to identify which driver i have to use to connect to Ms Access from my application. whether to use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB 4.0 or Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB 12.0 or something else?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** You can get the `Ms-Access` version from widows `Registry` and apply the respective connection string.

Comment: Alright. Furthermore how to identify whether i have to user Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB 4.0 or Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB 12.0